# Postgresql regex to match uppercase, Unicode-aware

Tags: regex, postgresql, unicode

The title sums it up pretty well. I'm looking for a regular expression matching Unicode uppercase character for the Postgres ~ operator.
The obvious way doesn't work:

```
=> select 'A' ~ '[[:upper:]]';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

=> select 'Ó' ~ '[[:upper:]]';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

=> select 'Ą' ~ '[[:upper:]]';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

I'm using Postgresql 9.1 and my locale is set to pl_PL.UTF-8. The ordering works fine.

```
=> show LC_CTYPE;
  lc_ctype   
-------------
 pl_PL.UTF-8
(1 row)
```

Comment: not a proper answer, but `Ą` matches `[[:upper:]]` on my local postgresql 9.2.1 (but not 9.1.6)

Comment: @araqnid Matches for me also in 9.2. What if you try with the collation in 9.1?: `select 'Ą' ~ '[[:upper:]]' collate "pl_PL"`

Comment: @Clodoaldo explicitly specifying the collation makes no difference to the results

Comment: So it looks like a bug which has been finally fixed in 9.2?

Comment: May be related to [bug #6457](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2012-02/msg00112.php) that got fixed when it was reported (but not mentioned in release notes as far as I can see)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regexp engine of PG 9.1 and older versions does not correctly classify characters whose codepoint doesn't fit it one byte.
The codepoint of `'Ó'` being 211 it gets it right, but the codepoint of `'Ą'` is 260, beyond 255.

PG 9.2 is better at this, though still not 100% right for all alphabets. See this [commit](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=e00f68e49c148851187136d3278b7e9afa370537) in PostgreSQL source code, and particularly these parts of the comment:

> remove the hard-wired limitation to not consider wctype.h results for
>   character codes above 255

and

> Still, we can push it up to U+7FF (which I chose as the limit of
>   2-byte UTF8 characters), which will at least make Eastern Europeans
>   happy pending a better solution

Unfortunately this was not backported to 9.1

Answer (score 1):

I've found that perl regular expressions handles Unicode perfectly.

```
create extension plperl;

create function is_letter_upper(text) returns boolean
immutable strict language plperl
as $$
    use feature 'unicode_strings';
    return $_[0] =~ /^\p{IsUpper}$/ ? "true" : "false";
$$;
```

Tested on postgres 9.2 with perl 5.16.2.