# multi byte character issue in Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, vertica

I am unable to convert multibyte characters in Redshift.

```
create table temp2 (city varchar);

insert into temp2 values('г. красноярск');  // lower value

insert into temp2 values('Г. Красноярск'); //upper value

select * from temp2 where city ilike 'Г. Красноярск'

city          
------------- 
Г. Красноярск
```

I tried like below, `UTF-8` characters are  converting into lower.

```
select lower('Г. Красноярск')

lower         
------------- 
г. красноярск
```

In vertica it is working fine with using `lowerb()` function.

Comment: May I ask what you're using/evaluating Redshift for?

Comment: I am using lower() function only .

Comment: " I Just want to convert only ASCII chars to lower case but not multibyte charactes", but lower fucction converting some of multibyte characters to lower ascii charactes. Later unable to compar them using ilike.

Answer (score 1):

Internally the `LIKE` and `ILIKE` operators use PostgreSQL's regular expression support.

Support for proper handling of utf-8 multibyte chars in regular expressions was added in PostgreSQL 9.2. Redshift is based on PostgreSQL 8.2 (?) and it looks like they haven't backported that support into their forked version.

See [Postgresql regex to match uppercase, Unicode-aware](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14277805/398670)

You can work around this, with limitations, by using `LIKE lower('Г. Красноярск')` instead. An expression index may be useful.

Comment: " I Just want to convert only ASCII chars to lower case but not multibyte charactes", but lower fucction converting some of multibyte characters to lower ascii charactes. Later unable to compar them using ilike.

Comment: @user2086435 Ah, that's a different issue. You didn't mention that in the original question. You're pretty much out of luck, you're looking for proper unicode support that isn't present in PostgreSQL 8.2.